# R studio: cannot debug/write in file with browser() during a function call

Tags: debugging, rstudio

Function 1 is called from the main script and code execution is halted by the command

> browser()

However the file seems locked and I cannot type and code whilst in debug mode. However I would like to debug with all the parsed arguments' values available.

Scope in R is global, but still, I want to debug while the code has all the values available for all the variables calculated so far...

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you mean by 'debug'.

You cannot edit function code while it is being executed. You *can* print the values of arguments and variables, and perform computations on them while stopped at a breakpoint (=="browser()") - from the R console.

You tagged the question RStudio - if indeed you're using it and all you need is to observe the values of variables calculated so far - you don't even need to type their name at the console, just switch to the 'Environment' pane (by default at the top right).

Comment: I see. What I like to do is to type/edit code in the called function while at browser() line inside the function code/file, as to as such improve the code. This is possible in Matlab. Why this isn't possible in R studio? Makes sense to have access to all previously calculated variables while writing code, right?

Comment: The jit apparatus in R doesn’t have edit-and-continue capabilities (last time I worked in matlab it didn’t have it either).  The closest you can do is edit your function code, select it and eval (eg via Ctrl+Enter) at the R console until you’re happy with the results.

Comment: Seems like you CAN edit function code while debugging a function with browser(). The source needs to be available though.

Comment: @babipsylon indeed you can, but what happens when you try to continue?  You're halfway through evaluation of no longer relevant statements.

Comment: I prefer the term "updated" statements :). Depends I guess...